# Search performance of non-clustered index on binary and integer columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, indexing, binary

I store fixed-size binary hashes less than or equal 64 bits in Microsoft SQL Server 2012 database. The size of binary hash may be 48 or 32 bits also. Each hash has an identificator `Id`. The table structure is like this:

```
Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Hash binary(8) NOT NULL
```

I created non-clustered index on `Hash` column for performance purposes and for fast way to look up of hash. Also I tried to create integer columns instead of `binary(n)` depending on bytes `n`. For example I changed the column type from `binary(4)` to `int`.

Are there differences between indices on column types `binary(8)` and `bigint` or between `binary(4)` and `int` and so on?
 Is it reasonable to store hashes as integers to improve search performance?

Comment: Did you come with an answer here? Pretty curious :)

Answer (score 0):

Under the covers the index is limited to a certain byte length.  The smaller the better for IO.  It's easy enough to convert between the datatypes using convert(varbinary(25),Hash) syntax, once you have the value of interest.  You don't want to invoke a ton of converts while you're looking up the records.

If there is a difference it might be due to the collations or statistics that are being used, which just says between two values if one is more, less or equal.  Statics enable the query to look past lots of values because it "knows" the data distribution.

When you have a large strings and you attempt to do like '%value' lookups, there's not much benefit much from the index.  Hashes should be random.  Which means the focus is on the number of bytes that are compared to make a query decision.  The fewer the better.

The unhelpful but accurate cya that every database engineer will tell you, it depends, you should test it.